# Can't remove event listeners from browser DOM

Tags: typescript, dom, dom-events

The problem is that I have two methods, one to initialize the event listeners and the other to delete them. When deleting the listeners in the console I see a successful message that the listeners were removed from the array of the component where they were, and when I try to access the component, I see an empty array as it should be. However, when I try to start interacting with the UI after deleting the listeners, I still see that the listeners were not actually deleted, and in the DevTools -> "Event Listeners" tab - I see that they are present there. And if I manually delete via DevTools in the Event  Listeners tab, it is deleted successfully, and works as it should. My assumption was that my `removeDOMListeners` method might lose context even though the array is being successfully cleared. I will be grateful for any advice.

Output result after calling method for removing event listeners:

> Listeners before removal: 1
> Listeners after removal: 0

DOMListener.ts:

```
export abstract class DOMListener<T extends DOMElement> {
    protected readonly $root: T;
    protected readonly listeners: string[];

    protected constructor($root: T, listeners: string[] = []) {
        if (!$root) {
            throw new Error(`No $root provided for DomListener!`);
        }
        this.$root = $root;
        this.listeners = listeners;
    }

    [key: string]: any;
    public initDOMListener(): void {
        this.listeners.forEach((listener) => {
            const method = prefixSetter('on', listener);
            if (!this[method]) {
                const name = this.name || '';
                throw new Error(`Method ${method} is not implemented in ${name} Component`);
            }
            this[method] = this[method].bind(this);

            if (this.$root && this.$root.on) {
                this.$root.on(listener, this[method]);
                console.log(listener)
            }
        });
    }


    public removeDOMListener(): void {
        console.log('Listeners before removal:', this.listeners.length);
        this.listeners.forEach((listener) => {
            const method = prefixSetter('on', listener);
            const listenerFunction = this[method].bind(this);
            if (this.$root && this.$root.off) {
                this.$root.off(listener, listenerFunction);
            }
        });
        this.listeners.length = 0;
        console.log('Listeners after removal:', this.listeners.length);
    }
}
```

DOM.ts:

```
export class DOM {
    public $el: HTMLElement;

    constructor(selector: string | HTMLElement) {
        this.$el = typeof selector === 'string'
            ? document.querySelector(selector)!
            : selector;

    }

    public on(eventType: string, callback: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject) {
        this.$el.addEventListener(eventType, callback);
    }

    public off(eventType: string, callback: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject) {
        this.$el.removeEventListener(eventType, callback);
    }

    public append(node: DOM | HTMLElement): DOM {
        if (node instanceof DOM) {
            node = node.$el
        }

        this.$el.append(node)

        return this
    }
}

export function $(selector: string | HTMLElement): DOM {
    const el = typeof selector === 'string'
        ? document.querySelector(selector)
        : selector

    if (!el) {
        throw new Error(`Element not found: ${selector}`)
    }

    return new DOM(el as HTMLElement)
}



$.create = (tagName: string, classes = ''): DOM => {
    const el = document.createElement(tagName)
    if (classes) {
        el.classList.add(classes)
    }
    return $(el)
};
```

Component.ts:

```
export class Header extends BaseComponent {
    static className = 'header'

    constructor($root: HTMLElement) {
        super($root, {
            name: 'Header',
            listeners: ['input']
        });
        console.log($root)
    }

    toHTML(): string {
        return `
            <input type="text" class="header-input" value="Sheet name" />
            <div>
                <div class="header-button">
                    <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                </div>
                <div class="header-button">
                    <i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }

    public onInput(e: Event): void {
        const $target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
        if ($target.closest('.header-input')) {
            console.log('Header input val:' + $target.value);
        }
    }
}
```

BaseComponent.ts:

```
export class BaseComponent extends DOMListener<any> {
    name: string;

    constructor($root: string | HTMLElement, options: {name?: string; listeners?: string[]} = {}) {
        if (!$root) {
            throw new Error('No $root provided for BaseComponent');
        }
        super($root, options.listeners);
        this.name = options.name || '';
    }

    toHTML(): string {
        return '';
    }

    init(): void {
        this.initDOMListener()

    }

    destroy(): void {
        this.removeDOMListener()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove event listener you have to pass *exactly* the same function.
When you `.bind` if it's not the same function anymore.
When you `.bind` two times, it's two different functions

You have to keep your binded functions somwhere

```
class X {
    constructor() {
        this.method2 = this.method2.bind(this)
    }
    method1(e: Event) { }
    method2(e: Event) { }
    method3(e: Event) { }
    test() {
        // not keeping a reference:
        let listener1a = this.method1.bind(this)
        let listener1b = this.method1.bind(this)
        console.log(`binds are ${listener1a === listener1b ? 'equal' : 'not equal'}`)
        
        // making references on instantiation:
        let listener2a = this.method2
        let listener2b = this.method2
        console.log(`constructor-binds are ${listener2a === listener2b ? 'equal' : 'not equal'}`)

        // making references dynamically: 
        let listener3a = this.bind('method3')
        let listener3b = this.bind('method3')
        console.log(`override-binds are ${listener3a === listener3b ? 'equal' : 'not equal'}`)
    }

    bind(key: keyof this) {
        if (this.constructor.prototype[key] !== this[key]) {
            return this[key]
        } else {
            return this[key] = this[key].bind(this)
        }
    }
}

new X().test()
```